# tcsh: Syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'

Tags: tcsh

I am writing a simple script that takes a user input number and outputs whether the number was less than, equal to or greater than 100. I am using tcsh and I keep getting an error at `set myNum -i = $<` on line 6 that states `syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'`. I have tried multiple different indents and small changes, but nothing is working.

```
#!/bin/tcsh

set myNum -i = 0
echo "Please enter a number: "
set myNum -i = $<

if ($myNum > 100) then
    echo "You put in a number bigger than 100."
else if ($myNum == 100) then
    echo "You put in 100."
else
     echo "You put in a number less than 100."
endif
```

Comment: What is the `-i` option to `set` supposed to do?   I don't see it documented in the tcsh man page.   As far as I can tell, `-i` is not a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code exactly and tested it.   I didn't get the same error.  Instead I got

```
set: Variable name must begin with a letter.
```

This error was caused by the `-i` option to `set`.

After removing the `-i` options from `set`, the script works fine for me: